# Is "and with" grammatical in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, conjunctions, parallelism

> We have registered nurses working on site with a nutritional background to provide weight loss advice to clients **and with** at least a 2 year working experience.

Is the part in bold grammatical?

Comment: Yes, it's fine, though the phrasing of the *with* clause is unusual. It means the nurses have a nutritional background and also have at least two years' working experience. You may be interested in our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: That whole sentence reads off to me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the "and with" clause implies that the following is true in addition to what was said previously. The nurses have a nutritional background as well as two years' experience. It does seem a little wordy. You may consider breaking it into two sentences, or changing the order of the qualifications, such as, "We have RN's with at least two years' experience working on site, with a nutritional..."